# How to set the field collection count programmatically

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I've a field collection in which I would like to set the count of the field collection programmatically. I have a taxonomy, if there are 10 terms for the taxonomy it must be the count of the field collection.

Comment: Do you mean the max. number of items in field collection base on the number of terms?

Comment: @JimmyKo if there are 4 taxonomy terms, if must be 4. For 5 it must be 5.

Comment: Drupal version?